# Equivalence partitioning understanding A<5 and B<5

Tags: testing, theory

I do not understand the following example. It says that a function X will be executed if either of A and B variables will be lower than 5. The go on and explains that there are three valid equivalence classes for inputs:

```
A<5, B<5
A=>5 B<5
B>=5 A<5
```

Why there is no class for A>5 and B>5? Is it because this would not be valid class? But why A<5 and B>5 is valid, is it because the function is still dependent on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They seem to be assuming only positive tests.

```
A < 5, B < 5
A >= 5, B < 5
A < 5, B >= 5
```

all result in the function being run so there is some outcome you can test. 
I wonder if the phrase "three valid equivalence classes for inputs" should rather be "three equivalence classes for valid inputs".

As you note there is also an equivalence class you can form for the invalid inputs `a >= 5, b >= 5` which could be used in a negative test (i.e. testing X does not run when an input in this class is given)

Comment: Thanks, so I got it correctly that ALL equivalence classes would also contains A>5 and B>5. Not sure about the = signs as they do mention it their set. PS: You were right about the wording, I typed it imprecisely.

Comment: That makes it much clearer then, yes you can make 4 partitions, 3 of which are valid 1 which is invalid, but that doesn't mean you don't want to test the invalid one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the criteria, " a function X will be executed if either of A and B variables will be lower than 5", only two test need to be made.

```
if A < 5 then execute X
elseif B < 5 then execute X
```

There are four cases:

A < 5 and B < 5

A < 5, B >= 5

B < 5, A >= 5

A >= 5 and B >= 5

Comment: But the book speaks about equivalence classes of (valid) inputs. A>5 and B>5 is equivalence class for invalid input, because no action is expected then.